# How to make my MVC 4 application to use Google OAuth 2 instead of OpenId

Tags: google-oauth

I have an MVC application that makes calls to google to validate its users. It seems that it uses deprecated protocol (by Google) OpenId.
Is there any simple configuration steps to make MVC 4 to use OAuth2 instead of OpenId?

My problem: receive err message: "OpenID auth request contains an unregistered domain: `http://mydomain` " on every call to `OAuthWebSecurity.RequestAuthentication()` or `OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication()`